# Spring validation annotation - How can I verify that a 2 character entry into a string is an actual US state?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I am trying to use spring to check user online input to ensure that the two characters they enter is an actual US state, is there any way of doing this, hopefully using a preset pattern? like, @State or something (if that was a legit annotation). Also, is there a good annotation commonly used for a String street, and String city field? That is other than @NotNull and @NotEmpty

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: http://codetutr.com/2013/05/29/custom-spring-mvc-validation-annotations/

Comment: I think you'll need to write your own validator.  I'd have a properties file, and make the validator check against the `Properties` object.

Comment: Don't give them an opportunity to get it wrong. Use a list box or similar.

Comment: List box or something won't protect against data submitted via javascript or some other programmatic submission. You should always validate on the server no matter what validation you think you are doing on the client.

Comment: A List box does sound nice and convenient, but what digitaljoel says does make sense, so I think I'll go with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no out of the box however you can create your own `@State` annotation , all you need is to define your annotation and class implementing ConstraintValidator(which handles the validation logic) E.g.

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = StateConstraintValidator.class)
@Target( { ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface State {

    String message() default "{State}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};     
}
```

```
public class StateConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<String, String> {

    private static final Set<String> CODE_MAP = new HashSet<>(){
      {add("AR");}
      {add("AK");} //add more codes ...
    };

    @Override
    public void initialize(String state) { }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
        if(value == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return CODE_MAP.contains(value);
    }
}
```

In the similar manner you can create other annotations.

Comment: I can't condone having "reference data" hard-coded in your application.  You don't want to have to release a patch if Puerto Rico becomes a US state, the Russians buy back Alaska, or Japan conquers Hawaii.  I would recommend having a properties file.  This would be useful to the GUI as well, if you're going to display states in a list box.  You could also include the state name, if you use properties like `state.us.AK=Alaska state.us.AL=Alabama` and so on.

Comment: @DavidWallace Thanks, You are absolutely right :) , I thought that it will be self evident and that's why haven't mentioned it. Moreover, we can go one step further and create some services which provides states names. and then leverage the same service to improve user experience E.g. `typeahead`